# Как оставить вертикальный скроллинг, и по hover показывать вложенный список?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Всем, привет!

`есть такой код` https://codepen.io/Sparks_/pen/EdYEdE

Есть несколько вложенных списков для каталога категорий

Все категории не помещаются в заданную высоту из-за чего потребовался скроллинг, но как тольк я ставлю скроллинг (overflow-y: scroll;), сразу перестаёт работать hover и вложенные списки не работают.

Подскажите как можно оставить скроллинг, и при наведении на элемент списка показывать другой список или другой элемент?

Открывается по click, остальные по hover.
получается так - либо список скроллиться , но вложенный не открывается.

Если убрать у родителя overflow-y: scroll; ,тогда вложенный список по hover, открывается, но у родителя не помещается по высоте весь список категорий.

Данное свойство находится в .outter_catalog li:hover .inner_group.

Спасибо.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Sparks_/pen/WaeKWG вот дополнительная

Comment: @ИльяОлегович в редакторе есть кнопка для вставки html-сниппетов прямо в вопрос. только код нужно обрезать до разумно длины :)

Comment: изначально так и планировал сделать, но не хотел кучу кода размещать, слишком тяжело будет просматривать сниипет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте высоту и overflow непосредственно для ul.

Comment: Дело в том что у меня внутри элемента списка может быть ещё несколько списков, если я им задам свойства, получиться наложение скроллинга.

Comment: Благодарю, понял!